# Modal BootStrap window can not be rolled back in components - Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem that I can not solve for months! I'm using a package of bootStrap and JS styles, in which I referenced them in my _Layout. On all the pages that are rendered and inherit from the Main page, everything works without problems. Just open the windows in modal, that the problems started to appear ... Note that the DropDown located in the page Index is stylized correctly, but the same dropdown in the Create view does not work.

[image]

```js
<div class="modal fade modal-primary" id="modalGenerica"  role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Customer</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="modal-content">
                    Carregando...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

For my modals to work, my controller returns a View "Create", but when it is loaded in modal (Set in Index), I need to play null for the Layout property, else the window does not open. (This could be a problem). I've tried opening Modals using PartialViews, but it also does not work ...

I'll leave the link to anyone who wants to take a look at the project:
 https://onedrive.live.com/?id=40838E65B9F8787E%21120&cid=40838E65B9F8787E

Comment: All the other styling works? then that style is being "stepped" on. Can you post the rendered html from the source view of the modal?

Comment: Yes. All styles are working. The problem is only happening in Bootstrap Modals windows. If you want to check the project, it is available for download at the link above ...

Comment: In the modal window, if all the other styles are working, then something is wrong with how that ddl is being rendered.  You run your code, examine the rendered html.  If nothing stands out then post the rendered html segment.  I have no intention of downloading your project but I will help you examine the rendered html.

Comment: Quando você diz "renderizado" seria para eu visualizar no navegador com o uso da tecla f12?

Comment: Sim, isso é uma maneira, você pode "inspecionar" o elemento modal. Ou você pode usar a opção "visualizar fonte" no navegador

Comment: There is a limitation on the character size of the post. Could not post rendered page. I copied the file to my OneDrive for download ... This is in txt format.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/?id=40838E65B9F8787E%21120&cid=40838E65B9F8787E

Comment: well I meant to extract just the rendered modal.  I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: I posted the rendered modal.

Comment: I don't see it, I see only the zip file and the full page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174055/discussion-between-fnostro-and-jalber-romano).